# Subquery returns more than 1 row error although I'm using "IN" keyword

Tags: mysql

Although I'm using `"IN"` keyword I keep getting `Subquery returns more than 1 row` error.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `message` 
WHERE `id_receiver` IN ( 
    IF( `to_`='user' , '36' , 
        IF( `to_`='group' , ( 
            SELECT `id` 
            FROM   ( 
                     SELECT * 
                     FROM   `user_position` 
                     ORDER BY `id`) `user_position`, 
                    (SELECT @pv := '100') INITIALISATION 
            WHERE  FIND_IN_SET( `parent_id` , @pv ) > 0 
                AND @pv := concat( @pv , ',' , `id` ) 
            ), ( 
            SELECT `message_group`.`id` 
            FROM   `message_group` 
            LEFT JOIN `message_group_member` 
                   ON `message_group_member`.`id_group`=`message_group`.`id`
            WHERE     `message_group_member`.`id_user`='36' 
        )
    ) 
)
AND `seen`='0'
AND `receiver_delete`='0'
AND `till_date` IS NULL
```

Comment: Could you please put a better formatting for your SQL code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner `select` queries return multiple rows. That is not allowed within an `if` expression. It would be allowed in a pure `in` expression, but as soon as you use `if`, that no longer holds.

So translate your idea into a series of `OR`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   message 
WHERE  seen = '0'
  AND  receiver_delete ='0'
  AND  till_date IS NULL
  AND  (   (to_ = 'user'  AND id_receiver = '36')
       OR  (to_ = 'group' AND id_receiver IN ( 
            SELECT id 
            FROM   ( 
                     SELECT   * 
                     FROM     user_position 
                     ORDER BY id) user_position, 
                     (SELECT @pv := '100') initialisation 
            WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(parent_id, @pv) > 0 
               AND @pv := concat(@pv , ',' , id) 
           ))
       OR  (to_ NOT IN ('user', 'group') AND id_receiver IN (
            SELECT message_group.id 
            FROM   message_group 
            LEFT JOIN message_group_member 
                   ON message_group_member.id_group=message_group.id
            WHERE     message_group_member.id_user='36' 
           ))
       )
```

I note that you use variable assignments in the first inner query. Be cautious with this, as there is no guarantee about the order of execution. I see that sub query is inspired by [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query/33737203#33737203), but please take note of all the disclaimers and warnings in that answer. They apply here.

If you can, move to MySql 8 and the recursive `with` syntax.